# Menu screen won't light on HTC Rezound

Tags: backlight, menu, htc-rezound

I took apart my Rezound (screen broke and I had to fix  it) and I lost those little plastic pieces that transfers the light to the menu.

What are these piece called? How can I find new ones online?